# For loop inside a asyncio routine not updating the loop variable. How to make canvas coordinates asynchronous and real time?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-asyncio

I am trying to record some co-ordinates and after the coordinates are saved in `x_prac`, I want to send the entries one by one from an asyncio routine to the main function. However, inside the for loop of `coorod()`, the loop variable `k` is not incremeting at all. On each iteration, I am receiving only the first entry of `x_prac`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pf import PF

import time
import asyncio

from tkinter import *

canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 150

DT = 1
NUM_OF_VAR = 4
NUM_OF_PARTICLES = 5000
meas_variance = 10 ** 2

# i = 0

x00 = np.random.randn(NUM_OF_PARTICLES) * 10
x10 = np.random.randn(NUM_OF_PARTICLES) * 10
v00 = np.random.randn(NUM_OF_PARTICLES) * 1
v10 = np.random.randn(NUM_OF_PARTICLES) * 1

initial_data = np.array([x00, x10, v00, v10])
nv = 5 ** 2

initial_weights = [np.ones(NUM_OF_PARTICLES)/NUM_OF_PARTICLES, np.ones(NUM_OF_PARTICLES)/NUM_OF_PARTICLES]

pf = PF(initial_data=initial_data, NUM_OF_VAR=NUM_OF_VAR, noise_variance = nv, NUM_OF_PARTICLES = NUM_OF_PARTICLES, initial_weights = initial_weights)

x_prac = []


def quit():
    global master
    master.quit()

def paint( event ):
    python_green = "#476042"
    x_prac.append([event.x, event.y])
    print(x_prac)

master = Tk()
master.title( "painting using Ovals" )


Button(master, text="Quit", command=master.quit).pack()

w = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
w.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

w.bind( "<B1-Motion>", paint )

master.mainloop()   

message = Label( master, text = "Press and Drag the mouse to draw" )
message.pack( side = BOTTOM )

N = np.array(x_prac).shape[0]

async def main():
    global x_prac
    global N
    j = 0
    mean = []
    while True:
        x_prac_iter = await coorod()
        x_prac_iter = np.array(x_prac_iter)

        x_predict = await predict_pf()

        H = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0]).reshape((1, NUM_OF_VAR))
        # print([meas_variance, meas_variance])

        if x_prac_iter.any:
            pf.update(H, meas_value = np.array(x_prac_iter), meas_variance = np.array([meas_variance, meas_variance]))
        j += 1
        print(x_prac_iter)
        # print(x_predict)
        print(np.mean(pf.x, 1))
        mean.append(np.mean(pf.x, 1))

    


    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot([mea[0] for mea in mean], [mea[1] for mea in mean], '-.')
    plt.plot(x_prac[0], x_prac[1])
    

    plt.figure(2)

    plt.plot([mea[0] for mea in mean], '-.')
    plt.plot(x_prac[0])
    

    plt.figure(3)

    plt.plot([mea[1] for mea in mean], '-.')
    plt.plot(x_prac[1])
    plt.show()

async def predict_pf():
    while True:
        F = np.array([[1, 0, DT, 0], [0, 1, 0, DT], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

        G = np.array([0.5 * (DT ** 2), DT, 0, 1]).reshape((NUM_OF_VAR, 1))

        pf.predict(F, G, dt=DT)
        await asyncio.sleep(DT)
        return(pf.x)

        

async def coorod():
    global x_prac
    
    global N
    global DT
    # print(DT)
    # print(N)
    
    for k in range(N - 1):
        print(k)
        return(x_prac[k])
        await asyncio.sleep(DT)



asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Here, when I print k, it is always 0. It doesn't update at all.

EDIT:

I incremented the variable in the main function and removed the for-loop. It works. However, I don't know if the use of global variables like `x_prac` is a good idea, to begin with. Furthermore, I want to make the canvas code asynchronously which I wasn't able to find a solution to. Now, I generate the coordinates in the canvas and store it in `x_prac`, and sending them one by one from coorod(). I want to somehow make it real-time. Is there a way to wait for the coordinates and use them real-time instead of storing them?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pf import PF

import time
import asyncio

from tkinter import *

canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 150

DT = 1
NUM_OF_VAR = 4
NUM_OF_PARTICLES = 5000
meas_variance = 10 ** 2

k = 0

x00 = np.random.randn(NUM_OF_PARTICLES) * 10
x10 = np.random.randn(NUM_OF_PARTICLES) * 10
v00 = np.random.randn(NUM_OF_PARTICLES) * 1
v10 = np.random.randn(NUM_OF_PARTICLES) * 1

initial_data = np.array([x00, x10, v00, v10])
nv = 5 ** 2

initial_weights = [np.ones(NUM_OF_PARTICLES)/NUM_OF_PARTICLES, np.ones(NUM_OF_PARTICLES)/NUM_OF_PARTICLES]

pf = PF(initial_data=initial_data, NUM_OF_VAR=NUM_OF_VAR, noise_variance = nv, NUM_OF_PARTICLES = NUM_OF_PARTICLES, initial_weights = initial_weights)

x_prac = []


def quit():
    global master
    master.quit()

def paint( event ):
    python_green = "#476042"
    x_prac.append([event.x, event.y])
    print(x_prac)

master = Tk()
master.title( "painting using Ovals" )


Button(master, text="Quit", command=master.quit).pack()

w = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
w.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

w.bind( "<B1-Motion>", paint )

master.mainloop()   

message = Label( master, text = "Press and Drag the mouse to draw" )
message.pack( side = BOTTOM )

N = np.array(x_prac).shape[0]

async def main():
    global x_prac
    global N
    k = 0
    j = 0
    mean = []
    while k < N - 1:
        x_prac_iter = await coorod(k)
        k = k + 1
        x_prac_iter = np.array(x_prac_iter)

        x_predict = await predict_pf()

        H = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0]).reshape((1, NUM_OF_VAR))
        # print([meas_variance, meas_variance])

        if x_prac_iter.any:
            pf.update(H, meas_value = np.array(x_prac_iter), meas_variance = np.array([meas_variance, meas_variance]))
        j += 1
        print(x_prac_iter)
        # print(x_predict)
        print(np.mean(pf.x, 1))
        mean.append(np.mean(pf.x, 1))


    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot([mea[0] for mea in mean], [mea[1] for mea in mean], '-.')
    plt.plot([x_pra[0] for x_pra in x_prac], [x_pra[1] for x_pra in x_prac])
    

    plt.figure(2)

    plt.plot(np.cumsum(np.ones(N-1)), [mea[0] for mea in mean], '-.')
    plt.plot(np.cumsum(np.ones(N)), [x_pra[0] for x_pra in x_prac])
    

    plt.figure(3)

    plt.plot(np.cumsum(np.ones(N-1)), [mea[1] for mea in mean], '-.')
    plt.plot(np.cumsum(np.ones(N)), [x_pra[1] for x_pra in x_prac])
    plt.show()

async def predict_pf():
    while True:
        F = np.array([[1, 0, DT, 0], [0, 1, 0, DT], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

        G = np.array([0.5 * (DT ** 2), DT, 0, 1]).reshape((NUM_OF_VAR, 1))

        pf.predict(F, G, dt=DT)
        await asyncio.sleep(DT)
        return(pf.x)

        

async def coorod(k):

    while True:
        global x_prac
        
        global N
        global DT
        # print(DT)
        # print(N)
        print(k)
        return(x_prac[k])

        await asyncio.sleep(DT)
    


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Does `N` ever change? I only see it assigned once (`N = np.array(x_prac).shape[0]`). My guess is that each call to `coorod` iterates once and that's it.

Comment: @dirn Yes, N doesn't change. So, are you saying that it calls it multiple times but it only iterates once? That makes sense. However, I don't know why. The for loop should finish first. I want it to send one value at a time like real-time. I don't want to read it from the beginning always and iterate only once. I hope you understand! :)

Comment: I just noticed that you `return` inside your loop. That means you always exit `coorod` during the first iteration. My guess is you want to `yield` instead, but all of the global variables make the code difficult to reason about.

Comment: @dirn Yes, I did one thing. I incremented the variable in the main loop and removed the loop in coorod() [I made an EDIT in the question]. That way it works. But I have seen in many threads that people ask not to use global variables. I also wanted to ask how to make it real time. My canvas functions you can see on top. I couldn't find a way to make it asynchronous. I really had to store it in `x_prac` and then use its entry one by one. Is there a way to make it asynchronous? Like, When I draw, the co-ordinates can be passed to the main function?